# Python 2.7 : Find and update xml using lxml

Tags: python, xml, search, lxml

I have below xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parserResult>
  <ParsedData>
    <Signals>
      <Signal>
        <Name name="asc_epsWarn_mu8"/>
        <Aufloesung ist="" soll="2^-0"/>
        <Min-wert ist="" soll="0"/>
        <Max-wert ist="" soll="1"/>
        <ErrorClass error="Signal does not exist in A2L file"/>
        <Bewertung evaluation="FAIL"/>
      </Signal>
    </Signals>
  </ParsedData>
 </parserResult>
```

I want to search for signal name and update the Aufloseung, Min-wert and Max-wert elements.
I am getting the `<Signals>` element from external source and then I am able  find the signal in xml.

```
signal_name = asc_epsWarn_mu8

 signal = signals.xpath("//Signal/Name[@name='%s']" % signal_name)
```

Now How can I update Aufloseung, Min-wert and Max-wert elements of this signal? I want an output like below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<parserResult>
  <ParsedData>
    <Signals>
      <Signal>
        <Name name="asc_epsWarn_mu8"/>
        <Aufloesung ist="23" soll="2^-0"/>
        <Min-wert ist="23" soll="0"/>
        <Max-wert ist="23" soll="1"/>
        <ErrorClass error="Signal does not exist in A2L file"/>
        <Bewertung evaluation="FAIL"/>
      </Signal>
    </Signals>
  </ParsedData>
 </parserResult>
```

Update : 
I tried below code but it doesnt update my values :

```
min_wert = signal[0].xpath('//Min-wert')
max_wert = signal[0].xpath('//Max-wert')

min_wert[0].set('ist','23')
max_wert[0].set('ist','23')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is with this:

```
signal = signals.xpath("//Signal/Name[@name='%s']" % signal_name)
```

You're intending to select `Signal`, but you're really selecting `Name`.

Change it to:

```
signal = signals.xpath("//Signal[Name/@name='%s']" % signal_name)
```

Also, when you do this (specifically the `//` in the xpath):

```
min_wert = signal[0].xpath('//Min-wert')
max_wert = signal[0].xpath('//Max-wert')
```

the XPath is searching the entire tree for the first `Min-wert` and `Max-wert`.

To search the current context (the current `Signal`) use either `Min-wert`, `./Min-wert`, or `.//Min-wert`. Since `Min-wert` is a direct child of `Signal`, just `Min-wert` is all you need...

```
min_wert = signal[0].xpath('Min-wert')
max_wert = signal[0].xpath('Max-wert')
```

Another alternative is to select "Aufloesung", "Min-wert", and "Max-wert" with a single xpath.

Full example...

**XML Input** (input.xml; added another `Signal` to show that the correct one is updated)

```xml
<parserResult>
    <ParsedData>
        <Signals>
            <Signal>
                <Name name="ignore me"/>
                <Aufloesung ist="" soll="2^-0"/>
                <Min-wert ist="" soll="0"/>
                <Max-wert ist="" soll="1"/>
            </Signal>
            <Signal>
                <Name name="asc_epsWarn_mu8"/>
                <Aufloesung ist="" soll="2^-0"/>
                <Min-wert ist="" soll="0"/>
                <Max-wert ist="" soll="1"/>
                <ErrorClass error="Signal does not exist in A2L file"/>
                <Bewertung evaluation="FAIL"/>
            </Signal>
        </Signals>
    </ParsedData>
</parserResult>
```

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

signal_name = "asc_epsWarn_mu8"

signal = tree.xpath("//Signal[Name/@name='%s']" % signal_name)[0]

for elem in signal.xpath("*[self::Aufloesung or self::Min-wert or self::Max-wert]"):
    elem.set("ist", "23")

etree.dump(tree.getroot())
```

**XML Output** (dumped to console)

```xml
<parserResult>
    <ParsedData>
        <Signals>
            <Signal>
                <Name name="ignore me"/>
                <Aufloesung ist="" soll="2^-0"/>
                <Min-wert ist="" soll="0"/>
                <Max-wert ist="" soll="1"/>
            </Signal>
            <Signal>
                <Name name="asc_epsWarn_mu8"/>
                <Aufloesung ist="23" soll="2^-0"/>
                <Min-wert ist="23" soll="0"/>
                <Max-wert ist="23" soll="1"/>
                <ErrorClass error="Signal does not exist in A2L file"/>
                <Bewertung evaluation="FAIL"/>
            </Signal>
        </Signals>
    </ParsedData>
</parserResult>
```

Comment: I am getting error when i set the value : 'list' object has no attribute 'set' . I used below code : signal = signals.xpath("//Signal[Name/@name='%s']" % signalOnlyInExcelFile['signal_name'])
            min_wert = signal[0].xpath('Min-wert')
            min_wert.set('ist','23')

Comment: Problem solved by using : min_wert[0].set('ist','23')

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the signal element, you can do a second xpath to get the Min-wert and Max-wert elements:

```
min_wert = signal[0].xpath('//Min-wert')[0]
max_wert = signal[0].xpath('//Max-wert')[0]
```

Then, you can set the attributes:

```
min_wert.set('ist','23')
max_wert.set('ist','23')
```

Comment: i got this error : 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath' .Error is on  line : min_wert = signal.xpath('//Min-wert')

Comment: I edited based on your comment. So xpath returns a list of items, since more than one item can match the xpath. You should probably add more safety checks, to make sure there is at least one match.

Comment: I found this out already but thanks! Now the line : min_wert.set('ist','23') doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: If you do right after min_wert.get('ist') you should get the right value. Once you are done modifying, you should save the xml tree back to a file.